# Flag/Mark Vagrant Machine As Provisioned

Tags: vagrant

I don't want to run provision on my vagrant (VirtualBox) machine. I want to `vagrant up` and the machine marked as "provisioned", even though actually the machine is not provisioned yet. I just want to mark it as "provisioned".

Is this possible? Perhaps, is there some file i can edit in `.vagrant`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems vagrant looks for the existence of a file :

```
.vagrant/machines/[machine-name]/[provider]/action_provision
```

However, it seems that there is more logic to that in

```
[vagrant-install-path]/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb
```

You can start investigating from there to what exactly vagrant needs to consider a machine as provisioned.

I personally didn't have time to look more into it since I fixed my issue with a workaround :).

Started the machine with *vagrant up*, so that chef_solo provisioner started running, and then hitting CTRL+C twice (so that chef says "exiting without cleanup") helped making the VM be marked as provisioned, so that it could be started without the --no-provision flag.

Hoping this comes of any help.